# No profile file found

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I start Visual Studio Code, the IDE pauses for a while, then the output window displays two instances of `[Info] No profile file found.` It does this for any folder I open, regardless of project type. I've uninstalled, then reinstalled VS Code, and even started disabling each extension separately to see which causes the error with no clear result. Any ideas?

[Visual Studio Output Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrRTc.png)

Comment: Are you setup up with and signed in to a Visual Studio profile? Top left of the IDE.

Comment: VS Code is not a IDE. It is an editor.

Comment: @Llazar how exactly is that helpful? Who cares what I call it - if you can't answer the question, don't say anything.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer It's Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio.

Comment: @JohnM.Wargo sorry John, missed that. I don't have any other ideas. Is it affected your dev in any way? As it is tagged [info] I would hope it doesn't have any real impact.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like my problem's unique since nobody had a solution and I couldn't find any references to it elsewhere on the Internet. I finally just decided to start deleting my Visual Studio Code extensions, on the second one the problem went away.

Now you'll probably want to ask me what extension it was, but I'd rather not say. I submitted an issue to the developer of the extension and it will be (hopefully) fixed soon.